# Resistance of a Wheatstone Bridge

Tags: noise, wheatstone-bridge

In the Whetstone bridge circuit:

[image]

If the circuit is balanced (and all resistances known), and we measure Vg as a function of time, then the fluctuations correspond to $$4K_bTR$$ the well-known thermal fluctuations. My question: what should be used for R here?

Comment: The equivalent resistance that the Voltmeter sees.Hint : nodes A & C are connected to the battery which is small signal ground.

Comment: That would be (R1+R3+R2+Rx)/[(R1+R3)(R2+Rx)]. What if all resistances except Rx have ignorable noise level, should the thermal noise seen by Vg be determined solely by Rx?

Comment: The only way that the noise contributed by R1, R2 and R3 is small compared to Rx is if they all have much smaller resistances than Rx.  However you specified that the bridge is balanced so that R1/R2=R3/Rx so that requirement cannot be met.

Comment: If all the R's were equal (R) the answer would be R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R1 || R2 sets the noise at point D ("||" means parallel)

R3 || Rx sets the noise at point B

These two noises (Vd and Vb) are added vectorially thus: -

Vnoise = \$\sqrt{Vd^2 + Vb^2}\$

Answer (score -1):

If all resistors are equal, then the Johnson noise of a balanced bridge is equal to the Johnson noise of a single resistor.

Source: Piezoresistor Design and Applications book. 
Extract available here: https://books.google.fr/books?id=I026BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA56&ots=NGGOlKVF5G&dq=johnson%20noise%20wheatstone&hl=fr&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=johnson%20noise%20wheatstone&f=false